# What's the difference between a cobbler, crisp, crumble, buckle, and betty?

Tags: fruit, dessert, language

I've heard all these terms at different times but never really understood the differences. What distinguishes various fruit-and-topping desserts such as a cobbler, crisp, crumble, buckle, or betty -- or are they all the same dish but with different quirky names?

Comment: You missed 'grunt'

Comment: Ha! Maybe I should make it a wiki ;)

Comment: And slumps and pandowdys! I think the general difference is that sometimes they have a crust UNDER the fruit, sometimes it's ON TOP, either crumbled over it or dropped, biscuit-like, into the fruit and baked that way.

Comment: Well, there's a start... If we want to go the wiki-route, that's cool with me.

Comment: Pandowdy? Okay, now I know you're just making up words. :)

Answer (score 18):

Some of the terms may be regional but they do generally describe variations on a theme.

My general understanding of the differences are as follows:

[Cobbler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobbler_%28food%29) - A cobbler is generally a thickened fruit mixture with scone or biscuit-like top crust. Cobbler crusts, notably "Texas cobblers" can also be made with thinner batters that soak into the filling more than simply sitting on top.

[This](http://www.blueberrycouncil.org/blueberry-recipe/blueberry-cobbler/) is an example of a blueberry cobbler with individual biscuits as a topping.

[image: Blueberry cobbler with biscuit topping]

[This](https://www.cookscountry.com/recipes/6646-texas-style-blueberry-cobbler) is a "Texas style" blueberry cobbler, where the batter rises up through the blueberry mixture.

[image: Texas style blueberry cobbler]

Crisp - A crisp is different as it has a "crispy" topping, usually made of a simple toasted mixture of butter, flour and sugar along with cornmeal or oats. The term is often interchangeable with "crumble".

[This](http://www.marthastewart.com/339882/blueberry-crisp) crisp has a topping of oats and optional nuts.

[image: Blueberry crisp]

Buckle - A buckle is significantly more cake-like with large pieces of fruit (usually blueberries) are suspended within. It often has a stresuel-like topping. In some circles, a buckle is also called a crumble.

[This](http://www.yummly.com/recipe/Blueberry-Buckle-1244536) is a blueberry buckle with a crumb topping.

[image: Blueberry buckle]

Betty - Also known as a "Brown Betty" is made with bread crumbs mixed with butter sugar and used as both a bottom and top "crust". These are very often (if not usually) made with apples.

[This](http://www.gourmet.com/recipes/2000s/2000/02/apple-brown-betty.html) is an apple Brown Betty.

[image: Apple Brown Betty]

Here's a [great resource](http://whatscookingamerica.net/History/CobblerHistory.htm) for the differences in the above and several other similar dessert items.

Comment: The Texas cobbler looks half-way to being a [clafoutis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clafoutis), as well as delicious. I'd be interested if there was a large French settlement in, or near, Texas in the early days.

Comment: @DavidThomas Nearby Louisiana has a very strong French heritage, so it's quite possible their cooking traditions migrated a bit westward :)

Comment: When I make a cobbler, the batter goes on the bottom, then then fruit on top. The batter rises up through the fruit. Then brown with a brown sugar crumble on top.

Comment: @Escoce ... that's the type I've labeled as "Texas style"... but it's not the "standard" method, really.

Answer (score 8):

This one's tricky, as there are some differences, but because different regions prefer one over the other, it's possible that some regions might conflate concepts under their preferred term.  I thought I could easy answer the question, but a little bit of online research suggests it's pretty messy:

- Betty (aka Brown Betty) : Originally used a butter/sugar/breadcrumb mixture, but I've seen it used for other streusel-like toppings.  Often have both a bottom & top bready layer (fruit in the middle).
- Buckle : Batter on bottom.  May have fruit on top, or fruit in the middle with a streusel top.
- Cobbler : Originally topped with a crusts like a drop-biscuit, so it bakes up like a cobbled street.  I've seen it used for batter and pie crust-like toppings.
- Crisp : Streusel topping.  Some say [it must contain oats](http://www.thekitchn.com/whats-the-difference-between-a-cobbler-crumble-and-crisp-90877), others say [it shouldn't](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/06/18/crumble-cobbler_n_3455487.html).
- Crumble : Streusel topping (whatever your oat rules say isn't a Crisp)
- Grunt : Slow cooked on a stove top (or campfire dutch oven), covered so it makes funny noises as it cooks and the fruit bubbles up and steams the topping.
- Slump : Some say it refers to how it behaves when you try to serve it, but others say you [cook the fruit down first, then top with a biscuit dough](http://www.history.com/news/hungry-history/pandowdy-buckles-slumps-and-grunts-americas-forgotten-apple-desserts).

Some other terms that I only heard of when looking up what other's people take on these are:

- Pandowdy : some claims it's [similar to a Betty, but sweetened with brown sugar or molasses](http://www.history.com/news/hungry-history/pandowdy-buckles-slumps-and-grunts-americas-forgotten-apple-desserts).  They also claim it's a northern name for the Betty.  Other sites say [it's a pie without the bottom, but you break up the crust after it's baked](http://www.blessthismessplease.com/2014/06/summer-fruit-desserts-explained.html) or [part way through cooking](http://dish.allrecipes.com/cobblers-cousins-grunts-buckles-bettys-sonkers/).
- Sonker : regional to North Carolina.  Baked in a deeper dish?

Every reference I've found says that grunts and slumps are the same thing (even though the descriptions of the dishes vary by source).  Pandowdy and Betty are frequently connected to each other in a similar way.